# How do I add sidebar with menu, using Display Suite?

Tags: theming

Display Suite layout just shows the full content for node, but I also need to place sidebar on node page.

I realized that I can't place main menu which I already created via menu settings in the sidebar. I notice that full content takes whole page. There is no way to add sidebar for the menu list.

How do I do that? Also how to have menu items set to active if this node is specifically linked?

Comment: If your theme has a sidebar then display suite will respect that.

Comment: Do you have a sidebar in your theme, along with a sidebar in your node display?  Or, do you have your theme sidebar disabled (or just not placing any content in it).  Also, can I show you how to do this in code?

Comment: @dwcdev - node.tpl.php does not have sidebar. so I have to add sidebar in the template? Also I need to know how to set menu set to active if the node is under same category menu item? Yes, please show me how to do this in code.

Comment: What I'm asking is if you want a sidebar, along with a sidebar in your node.  I think you're confusing the Display Suite sidebar in the node with the sidebar in your theme.  They are different.  The sidebar in your node just renders within the content region, while the sidebar in your theme is another region entirely.  So, are you happy with your node layout as is?  If so, then we need to add a sidebar region to your theme.

Comment: @Dwcdev - oh ok so i add sidebar in node.tpl.php and then add block to the region?

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: @dwcdev - Im using Open Framework from Stanford - https://openframework.stanford.edu/. cos i tried bootstrap module which doesnt work. Omega is a bit complicated. I have to do drush but how to do it on live server.